# What would be the aldol condensation products in B

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, aldol-reaction

In this question (13) I figured out A,C were wrong and D would be correct choice but I am stuck at finding out products formed in  B and also why it would be wrong?
Please help.[image]

Comment: When you have a mixture of two aldehydes under aldol conditions it is always possible to get self-condensation of one of the aldehydes.

Comment: But is is given equimolar mixture? I think may be in in B the para CH3 can lose H and become carbanion and attack acetophenone giving aldol product. Is the logic right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B is the correct answer, but not for the reasons you have given.

4-Me-benzaldehyde cannot self-condense, and is a far more reactive electrophile than acetophenone.  Acetophenone has a pKa of around 16 so will readily undergo base-catalysed aldol reaction with the aldehyde. This is the only reaction that will occur. All the other sets of reactants shown are likely to undergo self-condensation as well as cross-condensation giving a mixture of products.